# OpenCV color analysis in HSV

Tags: java, opencv, hsv

As the title suggests, I am interested in getting the HSV value of a specific pixel using java CV. This sounds easy enough, and it seems to be straight forward in C++ or Python, but I simply cant figure out how to do it in Java. I am pretty new to OpenCV, and if I decide to do more projects using this library I will definitely write them in C++ or Python.

For reference, my goal is to do a color analysis of an object that has varying levels of lighting. The end goal is to be able to take an image of something like a t-shirt and be able to say "this t shirt is x% red".

Here is some of the code I was using. Surprisingly inRange() takes much longer than just looping through every pixel and getting RGB one by one. I want to be able to do exactly this, just with the HSV color space. If you know of a better way to accomplish this goal, please let me know as this has destroyed my entire Saturday. Thanks!

```
        Scalar min = new Scalar(22,11,3);
        Scalar max = new Scalar(103,87,74);
        int sum = 0;

        System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME ); 
        File input = new File("bluesample.jpg"); 
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);  

        byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Mat mat1 = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC3);

        mat.put(0, 0, data);

        Core.inRange(mat, min, max, mat1);
        System.out.println(mat1.total());
        System.out.println(mat1.total());

        for (int i=0;i<mat1.rows(); i++ ){
            for (int j=0;i<mat1.cols();j++){
                sum += mat1.get(j, i, data);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum/mat1.total());
```

EDIT:

```
try { System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME ); 
    File input = new File("singlehsvpix.jpg"); 
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);  

    byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    mat.put(0, 0, data);

    Mat mat1 = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
    System.out.println(mat1.dump());
    byte[] data1 = new byte[mat1.rows() * mat1.cols() * (int)(mat1.elemSize())];
    mat1.get(0, 0, data1);
    //BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(mat1.cols(),mat1.rows(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(mat1.cols(),mat1.rows(), 5);
    image1.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, mat1.cols(), mat1.rows(), data1);

    File output = new File("PLS!.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(image1, "jpg", output); 
    System.out.println(mat1.get(0, 0, data1));   // RELEVANT LINE
    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (Exception e) { 
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Is printing:

```
[ 54, 213, 193]
3
Done
```

For this pic, 54, 213, 193 are the BGR values... I guess I don't understand enough about OpenCV to know why my mat1.get is printing 3

Comment: I'd suggest you not to write whole code, just write something like I showed, after finding what you need, then put exceptions, img.write etc. Your code has a lot of unnecessary stuff

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to convert rgb to hsv.

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(im_rgb, im_hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
```

Then, process as you like

Edit: in your code, change **mat** to **mat1**

```
for (int i=0;i<mat1.rows(); i++ ){ 
    for (int j=0;i<mat1.cols();j++){
         sum += mat.get(j, i, data);  //this line
    } 
} 
System.out.println(sum/mat1.total());
```

You are adding the value in original matrix.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am doing when I convert my photo to the HSV color space. My question is, how can I see the HSV values from that point? All of the methods that I'm using give me RGB values.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have another mistake in the code but I wrote about a mistake I think I saw. Edit and let me know if it helped, pls.

Comment: thanks, that was a mistake that I didn't notice. The problem im having really doesn't have anything to do with that code however. I just want to be able to print the HSV values of a pixel. I cant seem to find anything that answers how to do that in Java, as all the documentation and previous questions are from old versions of java ~2011

Comment: Maybe I'm not up to date, but I don't see the problem. Just convert your original matrix to hsv using the first. Then, `System.out.println(hsv_mat.get(i,j, k))` will print the corresponding point.  If `k = 0` it will print hue value, so on so forth